# How to turn datetime to format('%H:%M') but still keep datetime type?

Tags: pandas

**df**

```
   USERID              op_time
    a          2020-02-14 14:54:07
    b          2020-02-12 17:01:31

The type of op_time is datetime64[ns].
```

**Goal**

**df**

```
   USERID              op_time         converted_time
    a          2020-02-14 14:54:07     14:54
    b          2020-02-12 17:01:31     17:01
```

The type of converted_time is still datetime object.

**Try**

`pd.to_datetime(df['lst_redeem_op_time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M'),format='%H:%M')` but fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python impossible, close what need are [timedeltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html):

```
df['converted_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['op_time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:00')) 
print (df)
  USERID             op_time  converted_time
0      a 2020-02-14 14:54:07 0 days 14:54:00
1      b 2020-02-12 17:01:31 0 days 17:01:00
```

Comment: Your answer seems strange. Why is there 0 days?

Comment: @Jack - Because timedelta need `HH:MM:SS`, there are no seconds, so added `:00`